# Mapping values from two array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, maps, reduce

I'm wondering if there's a way to do what I can do below with Python, in Ruby:

```
sum = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(lambda x, y: x * y, weights, data))
```

I have two arrays of equal sizes with the weights and data but I can't seem to find a function similar to map in Ruby, reduce I have working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@Michiel de Mare

Your Ruby 1.9 example can be shortened a bit further:

```
weights.zip(data).map(:*).reduce(:+)
```

Also note that in Ruby 1.8, if you require ActiveSupport (from Rails) you can use:

```
weights.zip(data).map(&:*).reduce(&:+)
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me on Ruby 1.9.3 (ArgumentError): `[1,2,3].zip([4,5,6]).map(:*)`

Comment: @FelixRabe: It seems ruby has changed how the arguments get handled in this sort of proc. I don't really know any details, since I haven't touched ruby in a few years.

Answer (score 6):

In Ruby 1.9:

```
weights.zip(data).map{|a,b| a*b}.reduce(:+)
```

In Ruby 1.8:

```
weights.zip(data).inject(0) {|sum,(w,d)| sum + w*d }
```

Answer (score 2):

The Array.zip function does an elementwise combination of arrays. It's not quite as clean as the Python syntax, but here's one approach you could use:

```
weights = [1, 2, 3]
data = [4, 5, 6]
result = Array.new
a.zip(b) { |x, y| result << x * y } # For just the one operation

sum = 0
a.zip(b) { |x, y| sum += x * y } # For both operations
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has a `map` method (a.k.a. the `collect` method), which can be applied to any `Enumerable` object. If `numbers` is an array of numbers, the following line in Ruby:

```
numbers.map{|x| x + 5}
```

is the equivalent of the following line in Python:

```
map(lambda x: x + 5, numbers)
```

For more details, see [here](http://www.globalnerdy.com/2008/06/25/enumerating-enumerable-enumerablecollectenumerablemap/) or [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001146).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for the map that works for more than 2 arrays as well:

```
def dot(*arrays)
  arrays.transpose.map {|vals| yield vals}
end

dot(weights,data) {|a,b| a*b} 

# OR, if you have a third array

dot(weights,data,offsets) {|a,b,c| (a*b)+c}
```

This could also be added to Array:

```
class Array
  def dot
    self.transpose.map{|vals| yield vals}
  end
end

[weights,data].dot {|a,b| a*b}

#OR

[weights,data,offsets].dot {|a,b,c| (a*b)+c}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
weights = [1,2,3]
data    = [10,50,30]

require 'matrix'
Vector[*weights].inner_product Vector[*data] # => 200
```